Problems with App on Flutter, my app don't loading
when starting the device outputs such lines in the log, after launching the application it just shows a white screen.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
 
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});


  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

the output is just a white screen on medium phone it's all white.
Here's the log

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode... Running
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... √ Built
build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk Debug service listening on
ws://127.0.0.1:58621/qHlI7Un4ZNE=/ws Syncing files to device sdk
gphone x86 64... I/ple.flutter_app(11624): Compiler allocated 4533KB
to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 E/emuglGLESv2_enc(11624):
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2183
GL error 0x502 W/Parcel  (11624): Expecting binder but got null!

I tried creating a new device on the same android version, nothing changed
